# Am I using synchronized wrong?

Tags: java, executorservice, synchronized

Been following the guide from https://winterbe.com/posts/2015/04/30/java8-concurrency-tutorial-synchronized-locks-examples/ and for what I can tell this should give me a count of 10000 but I get very inconsistent results ranging between 3000-8000. Is the synchronized keyword not working as intended or am I doing something wrong? The increment() method gives the same kind of results.

```
  int count = 0;
    public void synchronizedIncrement(){
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

        IntStream.range(0, 10000)
                .forEach(i -> executor.submit(this::incrementSync));

        executor.shutdownNow();
        System.out.println("Incremented count by: " +count);
    }
    void incrementSync(){
        synchronized(this) {
            count = count + 1;
        }
    }
    ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    void increment() {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            count++;
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Adding a call to `ExecutorService#awaitTermination` after shutting it down should do the trick. Reason: you print the value of count before the threads are done with updating them.

Comment: shutdownNow() doesn't wait for the threads to finish. Use shutdown() and also use `future.get()`for the list of tasks created to wait for the result to finish. This should do the trick: `IntStream.range(0, 10000)
                .map(i -> executor.submit(this::incrementSync)).forEach(Future::get);`

Comment: @mrkachariker that may give the correct answer (although you would need to use `mapObj` rather than `map` for this to compile), but it won't actually run the methods concurrently. Stream mapping operations are _lazy_, which means that it won't execute the provided function until just before the `forEach` operation for each element. It will submit each task, then immediately wait for it before scheduling the next one, just as if the `submit` and `get` were written in the body of a single for loop. Not relevant for this contrived example, but important for real code.

Comment: @TimMoore thank you for clarifying that! I had my doubts too, whether the tasks would be executed in parallel or not in the functional paradigm that was introduced. What if we would add `.parallel()` before the map? Would it run the tasks in parallel in this case?

Comment: @mrkachariker yes I believe it would, because in that case the entire pipeline is distributed across multiple threads. In that case, explicitly using an `ExecutorService` is redundant. Of course, given that the tasks submitted to it in this example are fully synchronized, it's redundant regardless. This is fine for the purposes of experimentation and learning, but it's important not to take away the wrong understanding when using it in a more realistic context.

Comment: Another option would be to collect the stream of futures into an intermediate `List<Future<Void>>`, which would force the `map` operation to be applied to each element. Then, that list could be iterated in a second loop or stream.